# Can anyone tell me what part or set this round Technic piece goes to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I bought a large lot of LEGO and need help identifying this piece and or its set.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That's not the best picture in the world, but it appears to be a [Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60208#T=S&C=59&O=%7B%22color%22:%2259%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), either dark red or reddish-brown.  The dark red variation has appeared in a [half-dozen Star Wars sets and two other sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60208&in=S), while the reddish-brown version has appeared in [just one set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75826-1#T=I).